# webpack avoid bundle splitting packages with size less than a given size

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

In our project, we utilize webpack's bundle splitting feature. However, during the build process, we have noticed that even small packages are being subjected to bundle splitting, resulting in a large number of generated files. To optimize this process, we aim to implement a condition where packages with a size of less than 10 kb are excluded from the bundle splitting. How can we achieve this configuration in webpack? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some of your config?  Have you looked into [`splitChunks.minSize`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksminsize)?  Make sure you aren't prematurely optimizing.  A small bundle that doesn't change often and is used on every single page is better than forcing it to be a part of a big one that has to get re-cached every week or so.